# javax.ejb.EJBException: Failed to read response, in wildfly

Tags: java, wildfly, jndi, remote-server

I have this Exception, please I need your support.

there are one wildfly20 instance to services and other wildfly20 instance to tier web.

Web tier consume jdni as service in remote enviroment. It's testing and work well with some methods.

Now, right here come the case. Some methods from jndi tier work without problem and web call it, and get resources well, But, some others when Web tier call jndi call receive this exception (**javax.ejb.EJBException: Failed to read response**).

Please, Let's me know witch could be the cause for this exception triggered?.

Any hints that help with that.

Answer (score 0):

every one.

I'm answer my own quetion for anyone with same issue, because I dont find information that I could use to resolve it.

Like I said I have two instance of wildfly.

1 web tier project.
2 JNDI tier with services.

In the web tier just add in the jboss-deployment-struture.xml hibernate dependency module. It's default wildfly in modoles set org.hibernate.

That's it.